# Xiaomi Mi A1 How to change the screen lock code NOT the sim lock code

Tags: lock-screens, xiaomi, mi-a1

The title says it all.

It seems there is no way to change the screen lock code for this phone.

I am not looking to change the sim lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not on stock ROM on that device but as I recall Settings → Security ( and location?) → Device Security → Screen Lock.

You need to enter your PIN to change screen lock